# Why can not I create a python file that named 'exceptions' or 'utils'?

Tags: pycharm

Pycharm creates ordinary text file instead of python file, when I want to name the file `exceptions` or `utils`. Syntax is not highlighted and dependencies can't be resolved. I can create `utills` or `exceppptions` but not `utils` and `exceptions`. Why can't I create files using these names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just a bug. Needed to restart Pycharm

Answer (score 0):

Because they are reserved keywords.

You can check the reserved keywords like [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/keyword.html).

```
keyword.iskeyword(s)
```

Or get list of keywords like this.

```
keyword.kwlist
```

Comment: Maybe I have made bad explanation. The issue: I want to create python package, and need some modules there. Like exceptions.py and utils.py. Django has their, why I can't?